# JavaScript set DOM object event dynamically on dynamically created DOM objects

Tags: javascript, dom-events

The following script:

```
var containerDIV = document.getElementById("sampleContainer");

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var dynamicDIV = document.createElement("div");
    containerDIV.appendChild(dynamicDIV);   
    dynamicDIV.onclick = function() { alert(i); };
    dynamicDIV.innerHTML = "Row: " + i;
}
```

when clicking on the dynamically rows the output in the alert box will always be "5" instead of 0, 1, ..

Do anyone knows a proper way to assign the `onclick` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [the closure power](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        dynamicDIV.onclick = function() {
            alert(i);
        };
    })(i);
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/zvPfZ/

Comment: thanks it definitely works!! I still can't understand why but i hope to get it after reading the mozilla dev article :) Have a nice day!

Comment: @steax Closures is one of the most important features of JavaScript. I suggest you to read about it. Good day ;)